# Is it possible to set up WAN connection on a VLAN (Cisco Router)?

Tags: cisco, nat, vlan, wide-area-network

I'm trying to set up NAT load balancing (or failover) with two ISPs on my 1941 router. The router has only two WAN ports and 4 EHWIC ports (which are basically switch ports). One of the WAN ports is currently being used for the LAN SIDE and the other WAN port is for the first ISP. My question is:

Can i create a VLAN on one of the EHWIC ports and configure it for my second ISP? (i.e assign an ip address to it, set up nat etc.) as i have done on the WAN port for the first ISP? If doable, please how exactly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there is no thing called WAN port , data ports may be Ethernet or serial . and i believe that port connected to WAN side in your router are Ethernet (RJ45) port . to connect the second ISP to your router you don't need any Vlan configuration you just need to enable routing on specific interface by issuing `no switchport` command under interface configuration mode and then assign the proper IP to this interface and start NAT

```
R1(config-if)#no switchport  
R1(config-if)#ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0  
R1(config-if)#
```